# PHP gzread, gzfile, gzopen, etc.. all strip tags off of XML and return only the values

Tags: php, gzip

I have .gz files that contain xml files.  I've tried every combination of all the different things shown in the code below.  Any time one of the gz..... methods "works" it returns the values contained inside the XML files will all the tags and metadata gone.  For example, if the xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<tag1>
    <taga>
         This
    </taga>
    <tagb>
         is the stuff
    </tagb>
</tag1>
<tag2>
    <taga>
         I get but only
    </taga>
    <tagb>
         This
    </tagb>
</tag2>
```

What I get is:

```
 This is the stuff I get but only This
```

Here's the code:

```
<?php

$mailfileObj->zipfile = 'path/to/gzfile.gz';   //ignore the fact that it says zipfile, it is a .gz file

    try{
        $opengzfile = gzopen($mailfileObj->zipfile, "r");
        $contents = gzread($opengzfile, filesize($mailfileObj->zipfile));
        gzclose($opengzfile);
        var_dump($contents);
        echo '<br>';

        //$opengzfile = fopen($mailfileObj->zipfile, "r");
        //$contents = fread($opengzfile, filesize($mailfileObj->zipfile));
        //fclose($opengzfile);

        //$contents = file_get_contents($mailfileObj->zipfile);

        $contents2 = '';
        $lines = gzfile($mailfileObj->zipfile);
        foreach ($lines as $line) {
            echo $line;
            $contents2 = $contents2.$line;
        }

        //var_dump($contents);
        //echo '<br>';

        //var_dump($contents);
        //echo $contents . '<br><br>';

        //$xmlfilegz = $mailfileObj->filename.'.xml';
        //$openxmlfile = fopen($xmlfilegz, "w");
        //fwrite($openxmlfile, $contents);
        //fclose($openxmlfile);

        $opengzfile = fopen($mailfileObj->zipfile, "r");
        $contents2 = fread($opengzfile, filesize($mailfileObj->zipfile));
        fclose($opengzfile);

        //$contents2 = file_get_contents($mailfileObj->zipfile);

        //$contents2 = gzdecode($contents);
        $contents2 = gzinflate($contents);
        //$contents2 = gzuncompress($contents);
        var_dump($contents2);

    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo 'Caught exception: ' .  $e->getMessage() . '<br>';
    }

?>
```

What is wrong here?  What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the page source. You're getting the data, but the browser thinks it's HTML and is trying to render it. Try adding `header("Content-type: application/xml");` at the top to tell the browser "this is XML" so it has an idea what to do with it.

Comment: Thank you!  So obvious now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting the XML in an HTML web page, so the browser is interpreting the XML tags as HTML tags.

Use `htmlentities()` to encode them so they'll be rendered literally.

```
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        echo htmlentities($line);
        $contents2 = $contents2.$line;
    }
```

You might want to show this in a `<pre>` block so the newlines and indentation will be preserved.

Comment: OMG.  I can't believe that didn't occur to me.  Thank you!